# Export Prometheus Metrics for Spring Boot Application in Kubernestes using Sidecar/ Adapter Pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-java

Hi All I'm working on designing a Kubernetes sidecar / Adapter pattern for the Spring Boot Application to export Prometheus metrics, I am aware that we can use maven dependency
`io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus` to expose Prometheus metrics directly. However, with my limited knowledge, I got to know adapter/sidecar patterns we can extend apps in Kubernetes without changing the code. Being new to the Kubernetes concept I am struggling to figure out whether it can be achieved to adapter/sidecar pattern or not.
With my research, I find out example to expose Elasticsearch Prometheus metrics using adapter pattern [example](https://learnk8s.io/sidecar-containers-patterns) where Elasticsearch does not support natively exporting Prometheus metrics.

I need help with the following points

- Since Spring Boot provides a way to export Prometheus metrics using a micrometer, is it the correct approach to use a sidecar/adapter pattern to export metrics?
- if yes can you please guide me on how can we achieve this using the sidecar/adapter pattern in Kubernetes?
- any example would be great help.

Answer (score 2):

One way of accomplishing this is using a solution such as Open-Telemetry. You can choose to auto-instrument your application using OTEL agents and corresponding collectors (that run as a side-car application)

An example of this for the Java Petstore is here : https://signoz.io/blog/opentelemetry-spring-boot/

While this is not for Prometheus , you get the idea of this. In place of the Signoz exporter here , you can export it to the Prometheus sink and auto instrument & also trace your application

Comment: Thank you [Ramachandarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6617152/ramachandran-a-g) for sharing this, I will try and let you know.